# Cast xml to varchar with no entities

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlxml

This code

```
    DECLARE @x xml
SET @x = ( SELECT 'A & B > C' FOR XML PATH('') )
PRINT CAST(@x AS nvarchar(1000))
```

Return:

```
A &amp; B &gt; C
```

How obtain my original string 'A & B > C'? (with no XML entities)

Comment: 13 question, 2 votes, no accepts. Do you know how this site works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @x xml
SET @x = ( SELECT 'A & B > C' FOR XML PATH('') )

SELECT @x.value('.', 'nvarchar(1000)')
```

If you absolutely need to use print you have to store the result from `value` in variable before printing.

```
DECLARE @x xml
SET @x = ( SELECT 'A & B > C' FOR XML PATH('') )

DECLARE @y nvarchar(1000)
SET @y = @x.value('.', 'nvarchar(1000)')

PRINT @y
```

Result:

```
A & B > C
```